# Using a require within a define

Tags: php, require

I am trying to use a require to place a table inside a define

```
   define('ITEM1','text '.require('../../targetfile.php').' More text';
```

The idea is to pull in a table thats need on each define without having to copy and paste it each time.

I've tried various things but nothing has worked, I'm hoping you can, thanks in advance.

The targetfile.php would contain a large table

Comment: The assumption must be that there's actual PHP code in the target file. You have a syntax error in the single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

`require()` includes and evaluates the specified file. It stops execution on failure. On success it returns `1`.

What you could do this this:

file1.php:

```
$myTable = '.....';
```

file2.php:

```
require('file1.php');
define('ITEM1','text '.$myTable.' More text');
```

`define()` can use variables because it creates the constant at run time.

Comment: I initially tried to use $myTable, but the table itself has $varible in it so it didn't work as the $varible was loaded before the $varible was set

imagine that above the define on line it looks like this
    $varible = "1"
    define('ITEM1', text **table to auto fill that contains $varible** more text;

Comment: It seems like this is another issue than what your original question is about. I don't think I am able to understand what you're trying to say.